# How to use user_load() for user on $_GET[] request in Drupal way?

Tags: hooks, users, entities

I'm trying to get UID of users on $_GET[] request, following is my module code:

**my_module.module**

```
function hover_card_init() {
  $module_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'hover_card');
  drupal_add_js($module_path . '/javascripts/hover_card.js');
  drupal_add_js(array('hover_card' => array('module_path' => $module_path)), array('type' => 'setting', 'scope' => JS_DEFAULT));
}

function hover_card_menu() {
  $items['hover-card'] = array(
    'title' => 'Hover Card',
    'page callback' => 'hover_card',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}

function hover_card() {
  $id = $_GET['id']; // Get UID using JS, not a Drupal way!
  $user_fields = user_load($id);

  if (isset($user_fields->name) && !empty($user_fields->name)) {
    $name = $user_fields->name;
  }

  $array = array(
    'name' => $name,
  );

  return theme('hover_card_template', array('details' => $array));
}
```

**my_module.js**

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.hover_card = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      var module_path = Drupal.settings.hover_card.module_path;
      var hoverUserDetails = '<div class="hover-details"></div>';
      $("a.username").hovercard({
        detailsHTML: hoverUserDetails,
        width: 250,
        onHoverIn: function () {
          var user_id = $(this).find("a").attr("href").split("/");
          var hover_details = $(".hover-details");
          $.ajax({
            url: Drupal.settings.basePath + "hover-card",
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
              id: user_id[3] // What should I do here? As this is not a clean and Drupal way :-(
            },
            beforeSend: function () {
              hover_details.empty();
              hover_details.prepend('Loading...');
            },
            success: function (data) {
              hover_details.html(data);
            },
            complete: function () {
              $('.loading-text').remove();
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I will try to write an answer later (It's late night here). Just to point you to the direction: you are not really doing this the *Drupal Way*. In your hook_menu implementation, you could use an autoloading paramater for `%user`, and return the HTML as an Ajax command, and use the Drupal's Ajax framework to send/retrieve data. ctools module has an example module with well-documented examples.

Comment: Hello @AyeshK, thanks for that help. I'll try to figure it out. In the mean time if you're getting an opportunity to solve this, then please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comment for the question, you should use placeholders in your menu definition.

```
function hover_card_menu() {
  $items['hover-card/%user'] = array(
    'title' => 'Hover Card',
    'page callback' => 'hover_card',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;
}
```

Then you can pass the user ID for the currently logged-in user to the JavaScript code, instead of passed the module path, which is irrelevant.

```
function hover_card_init() {
  $module_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'hover_card');
  drupal_add_js($module_path . '/javascripts/hover_card.js');
  drupal_add_js(array('hover_card' => array('user_id' => $GLOBALS['user']->uid)), array('type' => 'setting', 'scope' => JS_DEFAULT));
}
```

The JavaScript code doesn't need to know the module path, since it will make an AJAX call to hover-card/%user which is not related to the module path in any way.